# associate form control with multiple forms on page

Tags: html

On my page, I have a form that uploads a csv file. I have a form that creates a saved search. I have a form that imports a saved search. And both in the form that creates a saved search and the form that imports the saved search, I need to send the actual file upload itself in the post request:

```
<form action="upload_file">
  <input id="file" name="file" type="file">  
</form>

<form action="create_search">
</form>

<form action="import_search">
</form>
```

So the file stored in the input field needs to be sent in the create_search form and import_search form, and the upload_file form as well, all of which are post requests.

Is it valid to do something like this:

```
<input id="file" name="file" type="file" form="create_search import_search">
```

Or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is your forms will be sent one by one, when the user clicks a submit button of some sort. If you want the same file to be uploaded on all your forms you have the option to duplicate that file input in all three forms using something like:

```
$("#form2").append( $("#file").clone() )
```

Note that you would have to modify the id of the input in order for the markup to be valid. Also, note that this might not be possible in all browsers, since cloning an input might be considered "editing it", and you should not be able to edit the value of a file input, according to security specifications.

P.S. You can't do it the way you intended in your example.

Comment: So javascript is required for this? html5 cannot do this out of the box?

Comment: Yes  you need javascript. No, there's no way to submit a file to multiple forms in standard html 5.

Comment: SHould I mark it as display: hidden, since I don't want the user to have to upload file again.

Comment: Yes, you would hide it in that case. I am not sure why you chose this complicated approach, however, instead of handling your file on the server side and using it whereve it is needed.

Comment: The only way to handle it on the server side is to save it in a session. You would prefer to store it in session than this?